# How do I convert below code to async await

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

```
const {Resource} = require('@google-cloud/resource');
const projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';
const resourceClient = new Resource({
  projectId: projectId,
});

resourceClient
  .getProjects()
  .then(results => {
    const projects = results[0];
    console.log('Projects:');
    projects.forEach(project => console.log(project.id));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

I need to convert this code to `async` and `await`. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: VS Code plugin? See https://dev.to/ben/visual-studio-code-can-now-convert-your-long-chains-of-promisethens-into-asyncawait-automagically-1b1b

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at any tutorials online? MDN has quite a few good references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to create an async function to use async-await.

Perhaps something like this:

```
const {Resource} = require('@google-cloud/resource')
const projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID'
const resourceClient = new Resource({
  projectId: projectId,
})

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const results = await resourceClient.getProjects()
    const projects = results[0]
    console.log('Projects:')
    projects.forEach(project => console.log(project.id))
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.error('ERROR:', err)
  }
}

run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy. It is very helpful.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped you out.